# Using `java.sql.CallableStatement` many times without closing it

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a [java.sql.CallableStatement](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html) with 3 parameters, and I need to call it many times, passing different values for the third parameters.

What is the right way to do this? I can create a new callable statement each time, but as far as I understand it would access to db.

The current code calls the same statement instance by changing the third parameter, without closing it and seems that it works. Is it normal to skip closing the callable statement?

It is running on MySQL jdbc connection.

Code snippet:

```
CallableStatement pivot = connection.prepareCall("{CALL pivot(?, ?, ?)]");
pivot.setString(1, "a");
pivot.setString(2, "b");
while(someCondition) {
  pivot.setString(3, "c");
  ResultSet res = pivot.executeQuery();
  try {
    // ...
  } finally {
    res.close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this way, which you have now, you save some steps in processing the call.
You see, each time you would prepare the call new, it would have to go on db through the optimizer which costs time and resources. Once your preparedCall is setup, leave it open (and chached on dbserver) for better performance.

You miss this in code:

```
if(pivot == null)
    pivot = connection.prepareCall("{CALL pivot(?, ?, ?)]");
```

you should keep pivot as field instead of variable.

Note: if you need resources and you have many preparedStatements and Calls, you should close the big ones which are not called that often.

I found this on microsoft: [image: diagram how it works] from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917694.aspx). I couldn't find any better picture of it.

Answer (score 1):

That's OK to have statement open for a long time if you manage connection yourself. However it's probably better to delegate this work to `DataSource` that have a pool of connections inside (check out Apache DBCP, or your JDBC driver may have a specific implementation as well); it will do the same, but generally with lower probability of an error. And with datasources you must always close statement and connection to return them to the pool.